# Linear Algebra Composition of commute ( can someone verify this )

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Let $(V, K)$ and $φ, ψ : V \rightarrow V$ be linear transformations.

Furthermore, we define the bracket of $φ$ and $ψ$ as

$[φ, ψ] := φ ◦ ψ − ψ ◦ φ$.

We say that two linear transformations commute if

$[φ, ψ] = 0$,

where 0 is the zero map. Show that if $[φ, ψ]$ commutes with $φ$, then
$[φ^k
, [φ, ψ]] = 0 ∀k ∈ N$
and
$[φ
^k
, ψ] = 0$.
Here, $φ
k$ denotes the composition of $φ$ k-times with itself.

Comment: It might be easier, and more general, to first show that if $\beta$ commutes with $\phi$ then $[\phi^k, \beta] = 0$.

Comment: but still is my approach correct ?

Comment: It is too hard to read, the question needs to be formatted.

Comment: Could you add some mathjax?

Comment: I dont know how to use it ? can someone edit it for me will be so grateful

Comment: @micky: Learn how to do it.

Comment: Is it better now ?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof of the first result is fine.

The second statement is false.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $[B,[A,B]] = 0$ but $[A,B] \neq 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by the second statement

Comment: Your questions states "show that if ...then ... and <insert second statement here>". Specifically, it asks to prove that $[\phi^k, \psi] = 0$.

Comment: @micky: Did you see what I meant by the second statement?

Comment: Oh Yeah , I was out of vision thanks dude

Comment: but I think its not related to the ( 1st one ) Its related to the fact if [A,B] Commute

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If $[A,B]$ commutes with what?