# Linear Algebra – Can someone verify my solution and help me in doing the second part?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $(V, K)$ and $φ, ψ : V \rightarrow V$ be linear transformations.

Furthermore, we define the bracket of $φ$ and $ψ$ as

$[φ, ψ] := φ ◦ ψ − ψ ◦ φ$.

We say that two linear transformations commute if

$[φ, ψ] = 0$,

where 0 is the zero map. Show that if $[φ, ψ]$ commutes with $φ$, then
$[φ^k
, [φ, ψ]] = 0 ∀k ∈ N$
and
$[φ
^k
, ψ] = 0$.
Here, $φ
k$ denotes the composition of $φ$ k-times with itself.

This is what I've done

will use $A$ and $B$ instead of phi and psi. Assume that $[A,[A,B]]=0$, that is $A[A,B]=[A,B]A$, that is $A(AB-BA)=(AB-BA)A$. The base case $k=1$ is what we assume. Now assume that $A^k (AB-BA)=(AB-BA)A^k$ . Then

\begin{eqnarray}
A^{k+1}(AB-BA) &=& A( A^k (AB-BA)) \\
&=& A(AB-BA)A^k \\
&=& (AB-BA)AA^k \\
&=& (AB-BA)A^{k+1}
\end{eqnarray}
so $[A^k ,[A,B]]=0, \forall k\geq1$.

Is this the correct way of solving if not can someone suggest a way of solving

Sorry I'm not that good with the format of this site

Comment: Yes, proving this by induction is certainly a good way of doing it. Your proof looks correct to me. You didn't prove the statement $[\phi^k,\psi]=0$ given $[\phi,[\phi,\psi]]=0$, also I'm not convinced this latter statement is actually true. Are you sure you wrote that one down correctly?

Comment: I think its given from [ϕ,ψ]=0 not related to the first condition , Is my induction steps correct

Comment: [relevant earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3414232/81360)